# ReferenceError: autocb is not defined

Tags: iced-coffeescript

After migrating to new mac book computer `iced coffee script` starts work incorrectly.

When I run script ...

```
iced script.iced
```

... I got error ...

```
ReferenceError: autocb is not defined
```

... on the row:

```
exports.method = (arg1, arg2, autocb)=>
```

On old mac it works good. Iced coffee script versions are the same on both machines. On both machines I can call `iced` in terminal:

```
iced
iced> a = 3
3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `iced-coffee-script` version. On old machine it was `1.6.3-f`

```
 iced --version                                                                                                                                                                                          ⏎
IcedCoffeeScript version 1.6.3-f
```

On new - `1.6.3-i`. I installed `1.6.3-f` and all starts work well on new machine.

```
npm i iced-coffee-script@1.6.3-f -g
```